# How can i use libshout library for os x project in XCode

Tags: objective-c, macos, icecast

there is library called libshout which provides functionality for connecting to icecast server. Could anyone tell how to include it to xcode project for os x application? Or how to compile it and include to the project.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, that it is possible to install libshout by homebrew for example, then it will be in /usr/local/Cellar/ along with other libraries it needs: libogg, libvorbis, speex, theora. Then you can add all those libraries to xcode project (.h and .a fies or all files..) with libshout, then just include shout.h header to you source file and you can use it.

Comment: Do you have any code/project example how you are using libshout in your iOS app? I need to do the exact same thing and do not really know how to call the libshout methods

Comment: I was playing with libshout the way you advice and that works perfect (thank you for that!), but for OSX. For streaming from iPhone device it should be another way. 
I am not familiar with libs building, just guess it should be built for arm64 arch somehow. So still looking for such a way.

Comment: @Jamal Here is [How to use shout.h](https://gist.github.com/TheTiger13/1146b8108ba93249f9a5e64f691ad558). I found this on internet.